# mount lacie 2T on debian server

Tags: usb, debian, mount

I have a server (OS debian), and to increase the disk capacities I wanted to plugin a LaCie disk (2T). Obviously debian didn't mount it automatically (like ubuntu does) which is not funny :). When I run df -h I got:

```
 Sys. fich.                                             Taille Util. Dispo Uti% Monté sur
 rootfs                                                   455G  7,6G  424G   2% /
 udev                                                      10M     0   10M   0% /dev
 tmpfs                                                    200M  776K  200M   1% /run
 /dev/disk/by-uuid/2ae485ac-17db-4e86-8a47-2aca5aa6de28   455G  7,6G  424G   2% /
 tmpfs                                                    5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
 tmpfs                                                    1,2G   72K  1,2G   1% /run/shm
```

As you can see, there isn't any 2T or 1,xT -> so the disk isn't mounted.
I looked at almost same problems on goole to see what others did to fix this, I figured out that I had to run cat /etc/fstab:

```
    # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
    #
    # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
    # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
    # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
    #
    # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
    # / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
    UUID=2ae485ac-17db-4e86-8a47-2aca5aa6de28 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro                 0       1
    # swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
    UUID=c1759574-4b7c-428b-8427-22d3a420c9e4 none            swap    sw              0       0
    /dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

And the my LaCie does not show up in this file either.

How can I mount my USB disk in this case?

Comment: You need to *edit* /etc/fstab to add your drive. However, you can completely brick your system this way, so perhaps you need to learn a bit more about linux admin?

Comment: Absolutely, do you have any good references ( that would be straightforward ) ?

Answer (score 0):

1. `df -h` only shows mounted devices
2. Which type filesystem are you using ? If ntfs you fisrt need to install ntfs-3g (which is provided by ubuntu in basic install but not in debian)
3. You can try to mount your device with the command `mount -t <fs-type> /dev/<sdxx> </mount/point>`

Comment: Thank youuu for your anwser, it should be a FATXX because when I set it up I chose a filesystem that can be read by windows, MacOS and Linux. Regarding the command mount, how can I figure out in which sdxx lives my external disk that I would like to mount?

Comment: You can use `sudo fdisk -l` or a simple `ls /dev/sd*` and guess which one you want to mount.